# How to apply chunk / modx template changes?

Tags: apache, web, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

I make changes to the template files, upload them via ftp (or through the admin panel). In the admin panel the chunk's code changes, but the site itself does not change. Why?

I tried:

1. Clear the cache through the modx admin panel - "Management - Clear
   the cache"
2. Delete the cache folder, which is located in the "core \ cache"
   directory
3. I tried to completely delete the template folder to check if there
   would be changes.
4. Modify the .htaccess file

None of this helped. There are changes in the admin panel, but everything remains as it was on the site

Website on MODX Revolution 2.6.5
In the settings of the server (hosting) it is written that Apache 2. * and PHP 7.1 are used

Here is the .htaccess file

```
# MODX supports Friendly URLs via this .htaccess file. You must serve web
# pages via Apache with mod_rewrite to use this functionality, and you must
# change the file name from ht.access to .htaccess.
#
# Make sure RewriteBase points to the directory where you installed MODX.
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]v(\d+)-.*$ index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^v(\d+)-.*$ index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^k(\d+)[-/].*[-/]v(\d+)-.*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^k(\d+)[-/]v(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^v(\d+)[-/].*[-/]k(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^v(\d+)[-/]k(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]v(\d+)[-/]k(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]v(\d+)[-/].*[-/]k(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]k(\d+)[-/].*[-/]v(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]k(\d+)[-/]v(\d+)[-/].*$ index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

#php_flag register_globals Off

#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5

#ExpiresActive On
#ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
#ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
#ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
#BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
#BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
#BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
#SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary
```

What to do?
Maybe someone came across a similar one?

Comment: What about your browser cache? How do you flush it? Is it the problem with just one chunk or with all of them? How do you call them? I mean like this - [[!...]]? Each resource has "cacheable" setting, what about it?

Comment: @curveball
I cleaned the browser cache, logged in from several browsers. Also "disable cache" in chrome dev tools was turn on.

This is the problem of all chunks and of the whole template.

I call chunks like this "[[$ ...]] "and like that [[!$ ...]]".

"cacheable" setting - where can I see it?

Comment: It should be on the tab "Settings" with other resource settings, like whether it is a container or not, etc.
https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources

Comment: @curveball thank you! How do I mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: glad to hear it worked out :) I posted  it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about your browser cache? How do you flush it? Is it the problem with just one chunk or with all of them? How do you call them? I mean like this - [[!...]]? Each resource has "cacheable" setting, what about it?

PS: setting "cacheable" should be on the tab "Settings" with other resource settings, like whether it is a container or not, etc.

https://docs.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources